# UI bootstrap dropdown toggle needs to be clicked twice if closed manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap drop-down component to show [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) calendar on click. I have also added a `$watch` to close the dropdown after date is selected.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R6lUTu2F9hRBb19kL1xo?p=preview)**

```
<div uib-dropdown id="calendar1">
  <h4>
    <a uib-dropdown-toggle id="calendar1-toggle" href="">Select Date <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'month', minView:'month' }"></datetimepicker>
  </ul>
</div>

$scope.$watch('date', function(newValue){                    
   angular.element(document.getElementById('calendar1')).removeClass('open');
})
```

The `removeClass('open')` worked but also brought a new issue. After you selected a date (`removeClass('open')` called) you have to click the dropdown toggle twice to make it open.

I looked into `uib` source code, did some digging and tried the following:

```
window.angular.element(document.getElementById('calendar1')).removeClass('open');
window.angular.element(document.getElementById('calendar1-toggle'))
  .removeClass('collapse')
  .addClass('collapsing')
  .attr('aria-expanded', false)
  .attr('aria-hidden', true);
```

But I still had to press toggle twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you attempting to open/close a `uib-dropdown` by manually adding/removing classes? `uib-dropdown` has an `is-open` attribute to handle that.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle because I want to manually close the dropdown after date was selected in a calendar

Comment: @JoelCDoyle If I understand correctly, `is-open` attr is only for initialization

Comment: Nah, dawg. They put that there for your convenience. Take a left onto easy street with me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually changing classes is not how you open/close a `uib-dropdown` why are you doing it that way? The docs clearly show the `is-open` attribute for hiding/showing the dropdown:

Markup:

```
<div uib-dropdown id="calendar1" is-open="dropdownOpen">
  <h4>
    <a uib-dropdown-toggle href="">Select Date <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
  </h4>
  <ul uib-dropdown-menu>
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'month', minView:'month' }">

    </datetimepicker>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
  $scope.$watch('date',function(newValue){
    //angular.element(document.getElementById('calendar1')).removeClass('open')
    $scope.dropdownOpen = false;
  });
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/touxnNRmnsefAMScCprC?p=preview